# What is the proper way of storing timestamps in Firebase if we don't want them to be editable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a `messages` node in my database with this structure:

```js
"messages": {
  "$messageId": {
    "text": "Hello there!",
    "created_by": "$userId",
    "created_at": 1501749790029
  }
}
```

and this rule:

```js
"messages": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$messageId": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    // required fields
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'created_by', 'created_at'])"
  }    
}
```

Seems pretty standard. But my problem is, this structure and rule allows any user to alter the value of `created_at` to any value, right?  The property `created_at` should be a timestamp of when the message is pushed and should not be editable.

Am I correct if I re-structure my database like this:

```js
"messages": {
  "$messageId": {
    "text": "Hello there!",
    "created_by": "$userId"
  }
},
"created_at": {
  "$messageId": 1501749790029
}
```

Basically, I will move `created_at` to a separate node so it cannot be edited by the user. I will then set up an event trigger via Cloud Functions that will auto-push the timestamp at `created_at` when a new message is pushed to `messages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to allow setting the `created_at` value only if there wasn't a previous value, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data)'s the doc

```
"messages": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$messageId": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    // required fields
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['text', 'created_by', 'created_at'])"
    "created_at": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
    }
  }    
}
```

Also, I think you may want to validate the owner of the message to prevent users from posting as other people adding this:

```
 "created_by": {
     ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.uid"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

After further researching, I found out I can make use of `.validate` and the `now` variable on Firebase rules to prevent invalid timestamps:

```
"messages": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  "$messageId": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".validate": "newData.child('created_at').val() == now && newData.hasChildren(['text', 'created_by', 'created_at'])"
  }    
}
```

This is less complicated than the one I thought of doing. Amazing.

Comment: This allows any auth user to pushe an object containing `text`, `created_by` and a `created_at` value with the current timestamp. If you want that field to not be editable, this doesn't work